# Is there a way to test for the throwing of an exception in a Ada unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, ada

I have created a handful of unit tests, one of which needs to test that an exception is thrown after a series of illegal activities takes place. This is a set of utility codes, so it is expected that invalid/illegal values would be input by some programmer at some point in the future.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073793/exception-handling-in-ada-during-unit-test) which uses the Ada unit test framework - in the present situation, that is not an option; however, I may re-work them to be able to use this (my understanding is that adding unit test projects to an existing legacy code base is a time-consuming process).

So- what should I fill into the body of this function such that it only returns true if multiple exceptions are encountered?

```
--* Returns true if an exception is yielded for test cases 5 and 6
function VerifyInvalidValuesCauseExceptions return Boolean is
begin

  --Run tests for 5 and 6, assert that exception is thrown for each
  --Not exactly sure how to do this yet

  return false;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working demo with multiple test cases in one verification function. I might prefer to give each test its own test procedure.

The idea is that test cases 5 and 6 are supposed to raise `Constraint_Error`, and others aren’t.

```ada
with Exception_Capable_Test;
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Verify_Exception_Tests is
   function Verify return Boolean is
   begin
      begin
         Exception_Capable_Test (4);
      exception
         when Constraint_Error =>
            return False;
      end;
      begin
         Exception_Capable_Test (5);
         return False;
      exception
         when Constraint_Error =>
            null;
      end;
      begin
         Exception_Capable_Test (6);
         return False;
      exception
         when Constraint_Error =>
            null;
      end;
      begin
         Exception_Capable_Test (7);
      exception
         when Constraint_Error =>
            return False;
      end;
      return True;
   end Verify;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
     ("Verify " & (if Verify then "passed" else "failed"));
end Verify_Exception_Tests;
```

The spec of the procedure under test:

```ada
procedure Exception_Capable_Test (Test_Case : Positive);
```

and its body:

```ada
procedure Exception_Capable_Test (Test_Case : Positive) is
begin
   case Test_Case is
      when 5 | 6 =>
         raise Constraint_Error with "failed with case" & Test_Case’Img;
      when others =>
         null;
   end case;
end Exception_Capable_Test;
```

This works (prints `Verify passed`) with GCC 6.1.0, 7.1.0 and GNAT GPL 2016, 7.

Comment: I appreciate your time- I'll adapt this into my code and see if I can get the compiler happy with it.

Answer (score 5):

```ada
Raising_An_Exception :
begin
   Should_Raise_A_Constraint_Error;

   Ahven.Fail (Message => "Exception not raised as expected.");
exception
   when Constraint_Error =>
      null;
end Raising_An_Exception;
```

Comment: Two problems I would have with this approach- I can only use it for one error at a time (maybe that is a fundamental limitation?), and I have no `Ahven.Fail` in my sources.

Comment: The `begin...exception..end;` blocks can be nested, swap the `null;` for one more block, where you add your next test case

Comment: `Ahven.Fail` is one of the reporting routines in the Ahven test framework.  It raises an exception, which is then caught by the test runner, and registered as a failed test. - You can put whatever you use to report a failed test there.

Answer (score 0):

So- what I ended up doing was a combination of Jacob's answer and some commentary. It turns out that exception begin .. end can be nested (yikes!).

```ada
--  Returns true if an exception is yielded for test cases 5 and 6
function Verify_Invalid_Values_Cause_Exceptions return Boolean is
begin

   Case_5 :
   declare
      Test_Output : Data_Type;
   begin
      --  Run conversions, assert that exception is thrown for each
      Test_Output := Function_That_Throws_Exception (Test_Case_5);

      return False; --  Should not get here
   exception 
      when Constraint_Error =>
         null; --  Should get here
   end Case_5;

   Case_6 :
   declare
      Test_Output : Data_Type;
   begin
      --  Run conversions, assert that exception is thrown for each
      Test_Output := Function_That_Throws_Exception (Test_Case_6);

      return False; --  Should not get here
   exception 
      when Constraint_Error =>
         null; --  Should get here
   end Case_6;

   return True;
end Verify_Invalid_Values_Cause_Exceptions;
```

Comment: I don’t see why you’ve nested this (masochism, maybe?! What happens if there are 3 cases? 4? 10?) You could use multiple consecutive blocks just like the second one, each with `when Constraint_Error => null`, then return `True` at the end.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it gave me a compiler error (it said an exception cannot be used here or something like that). Maybe you could show me what I did wrong? Ada is very sensitive.

Comment: That should probably be a new question.  But I agree with Simon that it shouldn't be necessary to nest the exception handling blocks in this case.

Comment: It’s not a new question - it’s part of this question. I’m trying to find the best way to do this. If you can improve on my answer, I beg of you to do so :)

Comment: @theMayer I've unnested your solution.